# gwt, many listboxes on the form

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I have a form with six listboxes. Data for every listbox loads through rpc.
I want load all data with one request to the server. I think to return Map< String, List < Seriliazible > > with data for all listboxes.

Other ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Astor's solution is really the best way to do it. I'd enhance it a little so you can have the data for each listbox separated (as I can see you want from your example):

```
public class ListDataForForms implements Serializable {
  private List<String>[] dataList1;
  private List<String>[] dataList2;
  private List<String>[] dataList3;

  getters and setters...
}
```

Doing it this way allows you to change your mind and send more or less information in the same request anytime you want